# MAX() and SUM() in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max

I have this table

```
dept | amount | price
   1 |      2 | 20
   3 |      2 | 50
   4 |      3 | 10
   2 |      5 | 20
   1 |      1 | 15
   4 |      1 | 30
   4 |      6 |  5
   2 |      7 |  7
   1 |      1 | 24
   2 |      5 | 12
```

dept is de department number
amount is how many of a product is sold.
price is how much the price of the product is

How can I found the dept, that has got the most money from selling their products.

I have this:

```
SELECT dept, SUM( amount * price ) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY dept
```

I need it to return the `dept` with the highest `total`.
I can't use MAX( SUM( amount * price ) ), so how do I do this?

Oh yeah. It's a school assignment and I may not use LIMIT or ORDER BY

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Then juergen's answer is what you are looking for

Comment: He is using a limit. I may not use the limit 1.

Comment: Why are WE doing YOUR homework? Will WE get the credit?

Answer (score 4):

Without using LIMIT you can try using HAVING:

```
SELECT dept,SUM(amount * price) AS total
FROM tab1
GROUP BY dept
HAVING SUM(amount * price) = (
    SELECT MAX(total)
    FROM (
      SELECT SUM(amount * price) AS total
      FROM tab1
      GROUP BY dept
      ) a
    )
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d8a9/7)</kbd>

Comment: You have the same solution to me. We edited at the same time, same thinking.

Comment: Our query may not return single row if there are two dept having the same total. In this case we may have to use LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use ORDER and LIMIT. This is a solution ( Tested)

```
SELECT dept, SUM( amount * price ) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY dept
HAVING SUM( amount * price ) = ( SELECT MAX(A.total)
                                 FROM
                                 (
                                     SELECT dept, SUM( amount * price ) AS total
                                     FROM table
                                     GROUP BY dept
                                  ) A
                                )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the total descending and take the first entry

```
SELECT dept, SUM( amount * price ) AS total 
FROM table 
GROUP BY dept
order by total desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the department with the highest total:

```
select top 1 dept, sum(amount * price)
from table
group by dept
order by sum(amount * price) desc
```

Comment: Just saw juergen's answer... The above is for MSSQL